# Problems bootstrapping Chef from Rubygems on CentOS5.4

Tags: centos, chef, amazon-web-services

I am new to Chef and am trying to install chef-server on an AWS t1.micro instance based on RightScale CentOS5.4 32 bit ami. I am bootstrapping from Rubygems following the [guide](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Bootstrap+Chef+RubyGems+Installation) from the opscode wiki except I installed Rubygems 1.8.5 instead of 1.7.2. I got stuck at this:

```
# chef-solo -c /etc/chef/solo.rb -j ~/chef.json -r http://s3.amazonaws.com/chef-solo/bootstrap-latest.tar.gz 
[Tue, 07 Jun 2011 10:36:21 -0400] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[chef-server::rubygems-install]"] from JSON 
[Tue, 07 Jun 2011 10:36:21 -0400] INFO: Starting Chef Run (Version 0.9.12)
[Tue, 07 Jun 2011 10:36:21 -0400] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[Tue, 07 Jun 2011 10:36:21 -0400] ERROR: Exception handlers complete /tmp/chef-solo/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/rubygems-install.rb:203:in `read': No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/distro/redhat/etc/init.d/chef-expander (Errno::ENOENT)
```

The file isn't there indeed. Is this a broken recipe or something else? How do I fix this?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

1) Downgrading to 1.7.2 did not help, same result

2) I also tried on a local machine with CentOS5.6 and Rubygems 1.8.5 and 1.7.2. Even more scary:

```
INFO: Processing package[erlang] action install (erlang::default line 26)
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.0/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:64: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-linux]
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your ruby version to atleast 1.8.6...

Straight from the opscode wiki:

> Ruby 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.9.1 or 1.9.2 with SSL bindings and development
>   tools to build RubyGems with native extensions is required

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Bootstrap+Chef+RubyGems+Installation